# Rename folders to lowercase in powershell

Tags: powershell

So first of all, yes, I did check before asking, and none of the answers work for my particular case.

I tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | %{
    $NName = $_.Name.ToLowerInvariant()
    $TempItem = Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "x$NName" -PassThru
    Rename-Item -Path $TempItem.FullName -NewName $NName
}
```

And this:

```
#Get the directories / sub directories and rename to lowercase
Get-ChildItem -recurse |
    ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.Name -CMatch "[A-Z]" } |
    %{
        $NName = $_.Name.ToLowerInvariant()

        # Set temporary name to enable rename to the same name; Windows is not case sensitive
        $TempItem = Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "x$NName" -PassThru

        Rename-Item -Path $TempItem.FullName -NewName $NName
    }
```

In addition to other things I tried on my own, and none of them work when the directory name is something weird like: "ASddwAfaSd [ sdfasd} []}] asdasd.asf".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I resolved this, but I'm still going to create the question with the answer, just in case somebody else has to deal with this:
The `-LiteralPath` switch will ignore all special characters, and so it can be used to achieve this desired effect:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | %{
    $NewName = $_.Name.ToLowerInvariant()
    $TempItem = Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "a" -PassThru
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $TempItem.FullName -NewName $NewName
}
```